# The License Plate Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The 7-digit license plate of a car happens to be a palindrome. Its first digit on the far left is twice the digit next to it. The 3rd digit from the right is odd and 5 more than 2nd digit from the left. The middle digit is the average of the first three digits on the far left. What is this license plate number?

HINT: A palindrome is a number that reads the same forward and backward. For example, 123321 and 6776 are palindromes.

Comment: Why is this tagged with real-analysis? I don't see any connection...

Comment: There is none @gcc-6.0.  New users, and especially those who have not yet been exposed to higher mathematics, often don't understand the many different labels we apply to genres of mathematics.  Despite this, when creating a post, the system encourages them to give multiple tags to their question so it can be more easily found by users.  I encourage @ omar and anyone else confused by this to stop and read the description of the tag(s) before deciding to apply it to a problem that it is unrelated to.  Better to have fewer tags than unrelated tags.

Answer (score 3):

The license plate is of the form $abcdcba$, where each $a,b,c,d$ is a digit.
From the information in the question, we know
$$
a=2b \quad\text{and}\quad c=5+b \quad\text{and}\quad c\ \text{is odd}
\quad\text{and}\quad d=(a+b+c)/3.
$$
Since $c$ is odd and $c=5+b$, we know $b$ is even. Thus $b$ is one of $0,2,4,6,8$. It can't be $6$ or $8$, because then $a$ would then not be a digit. This leaves that $b$ is $0$, $2$, or $4$.

If $b=0$, then $a=0$ and $c=5$ so that $d=(0+0+5)/3$ is not a digit.

If $b=2$, then $a=4$ and $c=7$ so that $d=(4+2+7)/3$ is not a digit.

If $b=4$, then $a=8$ and $c=9$ so that $d=(8+4+9)/3=7$.

Therefore the number is $8497948$.

Answer (score 3):

Ok lets do this systematically. Note that as we have a palindrome the third digit from the right is the same as the third digit from the left. If we let $a$ be the second digit then using the relations we are given we can see that the number plate must be $(2a,a,5+a,\frac{5+4a}{3},5+a,a,2a)$. Note that we immediately get that $a < 5$ as otherwise the third digit is more than 9 so not a single digit. Also note that if $a \neq 1,4$ then the fraction is not an integer so we get that either $a = 1$ or $a = 4$. Also if $a = 1$ we have that our third digit from the right is $5+1 = 6$ which is not odd. Hence we have that $a = 4$ and the number plate is $8497948$ .